# error in use Media in javaFX in java netbeans

Tags: java, media

I am new in java, and to learn more I am writing a media player in  "javaFX" using media classes. I get an error and I am not sure what is causing this and how to fix it.I have "NetBeans IDE 8.0" and jdk7 64-bit in Fedora 18.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{


    Media media=new Media("Path of movie");
    MediaPlayer player=new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView view=new MediaView(player);

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(view);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400,Color.BLACK);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    player.play();

}
```

but I get this error:

```
    error: constructor Media in class Media cannot be applied to given types;
    Media media=new Media("");
    required: no arguments
    found: String
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

How can I fix it?

I have two other questions :

1.what do I do that program plays Full HD video?

2.how can limit program to play just mkv format?

Thanks for your kind answers.

Comment: Probably the problem is about the library you import. Can you check whether the library you import is "javafx.scene.media.Media;" or not.

Comment: Personally I chose to switch to the java 8 version of JavaFX early on. **They differ somewahat**, and sample code using the shorter notation with lambdas are painful to adapt. (Sanity check: is the class Media indeed `javafx.scene.media.Media`?)

Comment: I try 'Import javafx.scene.media.Media' but get this error 'error: mediaPlayer.Media is already defined in this compilation unit'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JFX, but try

```
Media media=new Media();
```

Comment: There is a class called Media in JavaFX and its constructer can take the file path actually.

Comment: thanks, but if I make constructer then the "MediaPlayer(media)" dont know media.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I don't know really what happen. I make another new project and do again, Fix my problem.